# In that or in the way that

Tags: word-choice

> Question:

In what way is the moon different from the earth?

> Possible Answers:
>
> 1.The moon is different from the earth **in that** there is no twilight or dawn on the moon but there is on the earth.
>
> 2.The moon is different from the earth **in the way that** there is no twilight or dawn on the moon but there is on the earth.

Which is suitable, in that or in the way that?

Comment: Where's the rest of the sentence? I just wanna know how different they are.

Comment: I can't see any point in using "in the way that", though I wouldn't say it is necessarily wrong.

Comment: I'd choose the first sentence and change **the earth** to just **Earth**.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine.  One is more "wordy" than the other without adding any additional information, so good *style* recommends you use the shorter version.

However, the overall sentence is more repetitive than it needs to be:

> The Moon is different from the Earth in that there is no dawn or twilight on the Moon.

I know that there are *many* differences between the Earth and the Moon, so the use of "in that" is a little awkward since it implies that you are going to present a (somewhat) complete *list* of these differences. For example:

> John is different from Jane in that he is taller, has dark hair, and also is not female.

Since you list only one difference, it makes me question why you didn't include the other differences.  If you just intended to describe one difference, it would be more natural to say:

> **One way** the Moon is different from the Earth is that ...